# I have over 3000 child pages - but I need a different main page

Tags: pages

I set up my website using WordPress. The goal, to have about 70 pages directly linked to the main page (my landing page) and most of those pages having anywhere from 5 to 200 blogs coming off each of those.

All seemed well and good until i realized that the reason I was seeing 'no parent' as the parent page of each of my 70 pages was because my main page is not a page at all, but merely a blog post!

Oh, no, what to do!

I tried creating an identical page to my initial blog main one. I also went into the settings>reading and checked off that I wanted the main page to land on this new page. I attempted to then begin transferring the 70 pages underneath that newly created page (copy of the original main blog).

But I soon found out that it won't work, because when I go to the second tier of pages, the url shows three tiers. I want my second tier of pages to have urls that show only two tiers.

this is what i want:

ttp://www.mainpage.com/

ttp://www.mainpage.com/child-page/

ttp://www.mainpage.com/child-page/grandchild-page/blog

but instead I have this:

ttp://www.mainblog.com/newlycreatedpage/child-page/grandchild-page/blog

I'm a complete newbie and not familiar with unusual jargon-like web building terms. Is it possible for me to change out the main blog landing site for a main web page, and switch the other child pages over to it so I can have a clean-looking url string?

At this point I am considering trashing over 3000 pages and starting from scratch!

Comment: It is a shame you don't have over 9000!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to go to admin/settings/reading and check that you set the page to your new front page, and make sure to save the settings.

It isn't uncommon for people to change the page and then leave admin without saving....